# Extra Space After newcommand

Tags: spacing

I was trying to write a macro to bold a name.  I used:

```
\newcommand{\authorship}[2]{\textbf{#1 #2}}
```

then in the text used

```
\authorship{Dave Bridges}
```

Unfortunately when run through pdflatex I get an extra space after the name.  So for example the line

```
\authorship{Bridges, D.}, M. E. Fraser and G. B. G. Moorhead.  2005.  Cyclic Nucleotide Binding Domains in the Arabidopsis thaliana and Oryza satviva Genomes.  BMC Bioinformatics 6(1): 6.
```

adds an extra space between the period after D and the comma.  How do I get rid of that extra space?

Comment: Seems like authorship should be given a first and last name separately: `\authorship{Bridges,}{D.}, M. E. Fraser...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you specify you command `\authorship` to take two arguments, you actually only supply it with one during a call like:

```
\authorship{Dave Bridges}
```

As such, `#2` is the following *token* (a `,` in this case), but TeX still prints `#1`, followed by a space, followed by `#2` (a **bold** comma). Using a macro like this

```
\newcommand{\authorship}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%
```

or even just

```
\let\authorship\textbf
```

would suffice. Of course, if you intend to highlight (**bold**) certain parts of a name, then something else needs to be done, like keeping your original definition, but with usage of the form:

```
\authorship{Bridges}{Dave}
```

Comment: `#2` is not empty. It _is_ the following comma.

Answer (score 1):

Although Werner has identified the issue and provided a solution to this problem, you might also look into the `xspace` package available on CTAN.  It can be especially handy when defining commands like these that might then be followed by punctuation of some sort.

`xspace`, however, would not have solved this issue given the example code provided because, as @Andrey Vihrov pointed out, the comma would still have been interpreted as the second argument.